# Bootstrap Progress bar not incrementing in android

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, android-bootstrap-widgets

I have the following code I would like to use to increment my progress bar slowly for 20 seconds

```
    public void progressAnimator(){
    final long period = 1000;
    timer=new Timer();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //this repeats every 100 ms
            if (counter<100){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        loaderLabel.setText(String.valueOf(counter)+"%");
                    }
                });
                mProgress.setProgress(counter);
                counter++;
            }
            else{
                //closing the timer
                timer.cancel();
                Intent intent =new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }
    }, period);
}
```

My problem is that this only ends up indicating 0% on the loaderLabel and then freezes without doing anything.
I had earlier tried this code but it only blinks 100% on the loaderLabel and fills the progress bar and then progresses on to the next window.

```
     public void progressAnimator(){
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for( counter =1; counter<=100; counter ++) {
                System.out.println(counter);
                mProgress.setProgress(counter);
                loaderLabel.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.loading) + " " + counter + " " + getResources().getString(R.string.percentSymbol));
                if (counter == 100) {
                    Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, R.string.welcome, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent loadMain = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(loadMain);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    }, 100);

}
```

If I increase the delay to 20,000 then it freezes at zero, What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer given by Kumar Harsh, I would suggest you do the following

```
 public void progressAnimator(){
    new CountDownTimer(total_duration, duration_of_one_step) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // code to be executed on every iteration
            loaderLabel.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0} {1} {2}", getResources().getString(R.string.loading), ((total_duration - millisUntilFinished) / 1000) * 5, getResources().getString(R.string.percentSymbol)));
            mProgress.setProgress((int) ((total_duration - millisUntilFinished) / 1000)*5);
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            //code to be executed on completing the timer
            Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, R.string.welcome, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent loadMain = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(loadMain);
            finish();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

That should solve your problem note that I multiply by 5 to get the progress to 100 otherwise it will stop at 20

Answer (score 1):

```
public void progressAnimator(){
    final long period = 1000;
    timer=new Timer();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //this repeats every 100 ms
            if (counter<100){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        loaderLabel.setText(String.valueOf(counter)+"%");
                    }
                });
                mProgress.setProgress(counter);
                counter++;
            } else{
                //closing the timer
                timer.cancel();
                Intent intent =new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }
    }, period);
}
```

In your first code snippet, you have instantiated a `Timer` object but you have not used it to set a timer. Also, inside your `Handler` instance, there is no loop that can ensure that the `counter` is increased continually. Also, if there was a loop to increase the `counter`, as in your previous code

```
public void progressAnimator(){
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for( counter =1; counter<=100; counter ++) {
                System.out.println(counter);
                mProgress.setProgress(counter);
                loaderLabel.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.loading) + " " + counter + " " + getResources().getString(R.string.percentSymbol));
                if (counter == 100) {
                    Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, R.string.welcome, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent loadMain = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(loadMain);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

The entire 100 iterations of your loop are being carried out in a flash as there is no `SLEEP` call to make the loop actually wait for 100 ms. You can solve this by adding
`Thread.sleep(100)`
before the end of the loop. However, this is not advised as it will cause the entire UI thread to be blocked for 100 ms. So I'll suggest that you use a `CountDownTimer` for this problem.

This is how you can use it:

```
new CountDownTimer(total_duration, duration_of_one_step) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        // Write code to be executed on every iteration here
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        mTextField.setText("done!");
        // Write code to be executed on completing the timer here
    }
}.start();
```

In your case, `total_duration` = 20000 and `duration_of_one_step` = 1000.

Comment: Hi thanks for that comment but just a quick question, does the code you have provided replace my codes? if yes how to I get to set the level of the progress bar?

Comment: No it does not replace your codes. You can insert your progress bar update code in the `onTick` function given that you'll have the total duration and the remaining time in the function on every tick, ie every time it is called